# JSON parsing issue

Tags: iphone, json

My code:

```
NSString *jsonString;   

jsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Create a dictionary from the JSON string
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
// Build an array from the dictionary for easy access to each entry
NSArray *places = [results objectForKey:@"description"];
```

I am not getting the result i wanted.
When I debug the code I am getting 2 key/value pair & 0 object for NSArray places.

Comment: link of JSON file:https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=solapur&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyC0K5UhV_BWmXhncIZEnbh-WG2RVQVgfdY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that you have 2 key/value pairs. The top two keys intact are "predictions" and "status". So you must first of all extract predictions (it's an array):

```
NSArray *predictions = [results objectForKey:@"predictions"];
```

and then iterate over it; also note that "description" is a string and to get the places you must split it using the "," separator:

```
for(NSDictionary *aPrediction in predictions) {
  NSString *description = [aPrediction objectForKey:@"description"];
  NSArray *placesInDescription = [description componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
}
```

Comment: still i am gettting 0 objects for NSArray predictions

Comment: there was a typo in the "predictions" name

Comment: sorry i din't got got what you wanted to explain.

Comment: just in case you copy and pasted the code, there was a typo between the quotes; if you don't spell the name correctly the array returned will be nil.

Comment: @anjum Please accept answers that have helped you - that's how StackOverflow grows and people will be more likely to help you in future

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use:

```
NSArray *places = [results valueForKey:@"predictions"];
```

Comment: use:  NSArray *places = [results valueForKey:@"predictions"]; and not "objectForKey" ..

Answer (score 0):

Works for me without any problems with JSON Kit!

```
NSString *jsonString;   

      NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=solapur&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyC0K5UhV_BWmXhncIZEnbh-WG2RVQVgfdY"]];

      jsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      // Create a dictionary from the JSON string
      NSDictionary *results = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];

      // Build an array from the dictionary for easy access to each entry
      NSArray *places = [results valueForKey:@"predictions"];

      NSLog(@"places %@", places);
```

Comment: what is objectFromJSONString?

Comment: its the JSONKit Method for convert a JSON String to an object. Did you use SBJSON ?

Comment: i have imported "JSON.h" not SBJSON

Comment: My app is crashing due to objectFromJSONString.

Comment: i have used JSONKit FrameWork

Comment: can you please check your responseData ?

Comment: responseData is fine I have NSlog it and Iam getting the whole Json String.